# Including MPI header file with user-defined macro

Tags: mpi

For including openmp, this worked :

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif
```

I wanted to have this way of including for MPI as well; so I wrote this :

```
#ifdef MPI
#include <mpi.h>
#endif
```

But this does not work. Cannot MPI be included in the same manner?

Comment: OpenMP is an extension to the language (it generally required an extra flag such as `-fopenmp`) so the compiler is aware of it and defines the `_OPENMP` macro among other things. MPI is just a library and the compiler is unaware of it so it cannot define an adhoc macro. You might be able to achieve this by hacking the MPI wrappers (`mpicc` and friends) but that would not be portable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work.  You need to tell the compiler that MPI is both a macro, and defined.  The shorthand for that is -D:

gcc -D MPI my.c

Example, test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

#ifdef MPI
printf("Hello, MPI\n");
#endif

printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```

Screen scrape:

```
jsmith@LOBSTER:~$ gcc test.c
jsmith@LOBSTER:~$ ./a.out
Hello, world
jsmith@LOBSTER:~$ gcc -D MPI test.c
jsmith@LOBSTER:~$ ./a.out
Hello, MPI
Hello, world
```

Comment: why are you using `printf("Hello, MPI\n");`? what I need to do is telling the compiler that wherever you saw MPI functions, include its appropriate header file

Comment: I'm demonstrating in the general case, that if you compile the code with -D MPI, then anything you enclose inside an "#ifdef MPI" will get executed.  And vice-versa.